# Where is to download google plugin for eclipse 4.4?

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

Some of google's service is blocked here,and I can't install google's plugin from update site.so where is to download plugin archive for eclipse 4.4?Currently,only archive for 4.3 is provide in google's official site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/core/4.4/zips/gpe-e44-latest-updatesite.zip

I had to do a bit of URL fiddling to find that.

Comment: thanks,but https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4 is update site,and I have told that I can't install from it,and https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download only provide download links for v4.3 or old version eclipses.

Comment: Hey, see my updated response. There's a direct link to the plugin in a zip.

Comment: its not there any more.. do you know from where i can get it