# GWT plugin for Eclipse Luna (Offline)

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I need to install the eclipse gwt plugin for Luna offline

I went to this [page](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip) but it's missing

Anyone knows if can I get it from some other link?

Comment: See accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621327/where-is-to-download-google-plugin-for-eclipse-4-4)

Answer (score 0):

The URL for Eclipse Luna is this one:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4

I can't find an offline way for 4.4, it looks like only 4.3 and 4.2 are offered off-line.

Comment: Thanks I know this link, but I need to do it offline.

Comment: one thing you could try is to do the installation on-line once, but through a proxy server that would cache the downloaded artefacts. You could then install from the proxyserver without requiring to be online. Or perhaps even construct and offline installation package from there.